# Opening a txt file with python and replacing only the first number with a desired new one

Tags: python, search, txt

I have 500 txt files which when opened always have the same structure but different numbers:

2 0.574 0.483 0.233 0.24

The numbers are separated by space (even though it's not really important I think). Only the first number is important. It ranges from 0 to 22 in all these txt files.

I want a script that openes all txt files in a folder, looks for only the first number and changes it to a desired new value.

So eg it could be that in all txt files the first number I want to change from 2 to 8 and a 1 becomes a 5, a 0 becomes a 14 and so on.

I tried a bit and found some other kinda similar examples here on stack overflow. But nothing worked for me, caus the numbers in these example should always be changed to the same ones.

Basically in the beginning of the script old and new values would somehow have to be defined, eg:

5 - > 9
0 - > 12
etc.

Could anyone help me? Thx so much

Answer (score 2):

So if you first create a dictionary on how to replace the numbers (like such `transition = {'5': '9', '0': '12'}` to represent 5 -> 9 and 0 -> 12)
then you can do the following:

```py
for file in filenames:
    with open(file, "r") as f:    
        line = f.readline()
    with open(file, "w") as f:
        splt = line.split(" ")
        f.write(transition[splt[0]] + " " + " ".join(splt[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) to modify the files inplace. It will replace the first field on the first line of each file according to the translations defined in `tr` in the code below.

If there is no translation for a given field, the line will be output unchanged.

In case of any invalid assumptions on my part, make sure that you back up your files before running this code. Or you could supply the `backup` parameter to the `input()` function.

```
import fileinput
from pathlib import Path

tr = {'1': '11', '2': '22', '3': '33', '4': '44', '5': '55'}

files = Path('.').glob('*.txt')

with fileinput.input(files, inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if f.isfirstline():
            field1, sep, rest = line.partition(' ')
            line = f'{tr.get(field1, field1)}{sep}{rest}'
        print(line, end='')
```